# Management UI for Spring Boot or Node js Applications

Tags: java, node.js, spring, nagios

We are considering migrating various integration services from vendor based solutions like TIBCO BW, WSO2 ESB, WebSphere Message Broker etc into custom Java (potentially SpringBoot) or Node.js.

Whilst it is relatively straight forward to migrate the service logic, e.g. get message from JMS, run XSLT, send to HTTP request, the missing piece that these vendor solutions provided was a Management UI which allowed you to:

- view the version deployed
- deploy new versions
- view current configuration (ports, queues, url's etc)
- start and stop services
- perhaps enable logging
- view processing statistics
- etc

I may have a few hundred different JVM's / Spring Boot applications or Node.js instances, that I would like to provide a Management UI for.

What free open source management UI solutions exist in this space.

Or do I need to containerise all of these and use some container management technology like Kubernetes.

Or should I be using something like Nagios for this management task, which is more of a monitoring tool, but perhaps could be used as a Management UI.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar use case couple of months ago. i chose the following technology stack and i was successful delivering a product in 2 months

1. Confluent Kafka
2. patternfly UI
3. Drools for rules engine rather than XSLT
4. Docker & Kubernates
5. Spring boot microservices
6. Netflix hysrix tubine dashboard
7. Spring cloud config server
8. MongoDB

All are opensource technologies, we didn't spent any $$$ but saved around 250K USD on vendor based licensed software

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot Admin Server allows to do the following:

- view the version deployed
- view current configuration (ports, queues, url's etc)
- perhaps enable logging

Spring Cloud Config Server + GIT as backend gives you management for app configs (with history).

Micrometer from Spring Boot 2 + Prometheus + Graphana allows to visualize application metrics.

Logs from your app in JSON format + logstash + Elastic Search + Kibana allows to gather logs from microservices.